# Raspbian is loading the wrong modules for wlan0 and wlan1

Tags: raspbian, wifi, modules

I have a few Pis running Raspbian 4.4.50-v7+ with a USB module attached. I would like `wlan0` to be the Wi-Fi chip and `wlan1` to be the USB module. It seems that sometimes it works, but other times it loads them swapped. Here is some more info:

```
$ readlink /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/driver
../../../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb
$ readlink /sys/class/net/wlan1/device/driver
../../../../../../../../bus/sdio/drivers/brcmfmac_sdio
```

The modules should be switched.  Is there a file upon boot that tells it where to load the modules?

**Edit:**
I noticed that when I boot without the USB device, then it will load the correct module.  I need it to boot with the USB device, though.

Comment: Join the club.  I asked this a while back and got an answer:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63749/how-do-you-unconfuse-raspbian-when-it-has-wlan0-and-wlan1-reversed - I got mine to work without using blacklist.